# A certain layer disappears at certain zoom levels in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, zoom

I have added a layer that is loaded into QGIS via a CSV file. At the beginning everything seems to be correct and the layer is visible in every zoom level. The layer is added with the "Watch File" option and is supposed to change its position when the coordinates in the CSV file change.

However, as soon as the coordinates have changed and the position of the layer has changed, it is no longer visible at certain zoom levels. Has anyone had a similar problem and knows how to solve it?

```py
    if(QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(self.ambulance)):
            layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(self.ambulance)
            rr = layers[0]
            QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(rr)
        if self.ambulance == "Ambulance I":
            coords_var = "coords1"
        elif self.ambulance == "Ambulance II":
            coords_var = "coords2"
        elif self.ambulance == "Ambulance III":
            pass
        
        uri = "file:/home/eams/Desktop/system/" + coords_var + ".csv?delimiter=,&crs=epsg:4326&xField=Longitude&yField=Latitude"
        vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,str(self.ambulance),'delimitedtext')
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
        renderer = vlayer.renderer()
        symbol = renderer.symbol()
        vlayer.triggerRepaint()
        #ZoomaufErstelltenLayerVersion2
        vlayer.selectAll()
        mCanvas = iface.mapCanvas()
        mCanvas.zoomToSelected()
        vlayer.removeSelection()
        
        watcher = QFileSystemWatcher()
        watcher.addPath("/home/eams/Desktop/system/" + coords_var +".csv")
        vlayer.triggerRepaint()
        vlayer.loadNamedStyle("/home/eams/Desktop/system/qgis_style_file/qgis_" + coords_var +".qml")  
        vlayer.setAutoRefreshInterval(2000)
        vlayer.setAutoRefreshEnabled(True)    
        vlayer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: This looks like a bug report. You could create an issue at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues

Comment: after you have imported the first time, go to Layer Properties - Does the file have an Extent set? Is it possible that the new coordinates are outside of the extent of the layer on initialization?

Comment: I have checked the extension in the layer settings. Unfortunately, I can't see anything unusual. Can you describe it in more detail or do you have another idea what the problem could be? Thank you very much !